# Animation list for gif image working slow

Tags: android, animation, imageview, gif, android-drawable

Hi since `android` doesn't support `GIF animations`. I have used a `frames.xml` file with `animation-list` for showing animations.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:oneshot="false"
      >
      <item  android:drawable="@drawable/heart1" android:duration="100"/>
      <item  android:drawable="@drawable/heart2" android:duration="100"/>
      <item  android:drawable="@drawable/heart3" android:duration="100"/>
      <item  android:drawable="@drawable/heart4" android:duration="100"/>
      <item  android:drawable="@drawable/heart5" android:duration="100"/>
      <item  android:drawable="@drawable/heart6" android:duration="100"/>
      <item  android:drawable="@drawable/heart7" android:duration="100"/>
      <item  android:drawable="@drawable/heart8" android:duration="100"/>
      <item  android:drawable="@drawable/heart9" android:duration="100"/>
</animation-list>
```

The `@drawable/heartx` files above are the individual frames of my `gif` image.
The speed of the animation is different on different phones.
It is normal on `hdpi` devices and slower in `xhdpi` devices.
can anyone suggest me a solution to show same animation speed on all the phones.

Comment: You could have different resources for hdpi and xhdpi (or just different integers), but I myself dislike the idea to guess in advance the screen refresh timing.